# How to love Spring Hateoas solving to simple requirements

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hateoas

Ok, I am trying really hard to love HATEOAS. Spring Boot with its REST repositories is amazing. Does everything I want. I just have two requirements that shouldn't be that uncommon. So how do I do the following:

Given I have the two following entities:

```
@Entity()
public class GameConsole{
    @Id
    private String name;
}
@Entity()
public Class Game{
    @Id
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    private GameConsole gameConsole;
}
```

Assume I have REST Repositories exposing the two entities.

**1 - How do I generate a table list with the names of the games and the names of consoles with one request:**

Request from GET - /games
Using whatever framework, jQuery, angular, doesn't matter, just populate the following:

```
|  Game console  | Game      |
|  PS4           | Uncharted |
|  XBOX          | HALO      |
```

The problem is that when I query /games, I get a list of games with links to /games/halo/gameConsole, and not the actual ID of the gameConsole.
So does this means I have to loop and query each item to get the game console name?

**2 - Drop down menu**

Lets say I have a webpage to edit my Game. And I want to add a dropdown menu and put the updated game console.
To populate my drop down, I query /gameConsoles and get a list of consoles.
Again my problem here is that the id I get from the game is linking to the /game/halo/gameConsole which can't be matched to any of the items returned from /gameConsoles.

How do I solve that?

Really appreciate the patience guys in case the answer is simple.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Spring Data Rest you can work with projections - [see here.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts)

Using projections, you can embed your referenced objects rather than getting a link to the resource.

Comment: Projection does on the item level, not on the list level. Unless I am mistaken.

Comment: You can use projections on the list level as well. If you make use of the @RepositoryRestResource annotation in your app, you can even define the default Projection for the items listed under "_embedded" by setting the  "excerptProjection"  option.